Click on a random video link on a YouTube channel with puppeteer
I am trying to automate puppeteer to make search on YouTube for a YouTube channel and click similar link I pass as a base URL and also click on random video link on the channel it works successfully until clicking the random video link on the channel and my code doesn't work, I passed many baseUrl values like m.youtube.com/watch
this is my code
async clickLinkByBaseUrl(page, baseUrl) {
        const result = await page.evaluate((baseUrl) => {
            // Create a regex to match links that start with the base URL
            const regex = new RegExp(`^${baseUrl}`);

            // Search for all links that match the regex in the entire document
            const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).filter(a => regex.test(a.href));

            if (links.length > 0) {
                // If multiple links are found, pick a random one
                const randomLink = links[Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length)];
                randomLink.click();
                return "success";
            } else {
                return "failed";
            }
        }, baseUrl);


        try {
            // Wait for potential navigation after the key press
            await this.webPage.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 5000 });
        } catch (e) {

        }

        return result;
    }

After a lot of test I check the browser inspect element as a viewer to see what is been shown as the a tag and found this
<a href="/watch?v=f2aklSJCrTM" class="compact-media-item-metadata-content"><h4 class="compact-media-item-headline" style=""><span class="yt-core-attributed-string yt-core-attributed-string--link-inherit-color" aria-label="CATIZEN WITHDRAWAL UPDATE #AIRDROP| Latest Airdrop Today by CryptoLense 2 views 3 weeks ago 6 minutes, 23 seconds" role="text">CATIZEN WITHDRAWAL UPDATE #AIRDROP| Latest Airdrop Today</span></h4><div class="subhead" aria-hidden="true" style=""><div class="compact-media-item-stats small-text"><span class="yt-core-attributed-string" aria-label="2 views" role="text">2 views</span></div><div class="compact-media-item-stats small-text"><span class="yt-core-attributed-string" role="text">3 weeks ago</span></div></div></a>

I later pass

/watch?v

as the baseUrl it didn't work
I pass

/watch

It didn't work too.

What does not work exactly? "I pass as a base URL and also click on random video link on the channel it works successfully until clicking the random video link on the channel and my code doesn't work" seems to contradict itself--does clicking a random link work or not, and what happens when it does not work, specifically? Thanks for clarifying.
